# Setting unique Session variables at Application level

Tags: c#, webforms, session-state, global-asax

I have a Web Forms application that does not have a login page. Technically a user can access any page directly. However, I need to be able to identify who the logged-in user is on each page. I don't want to add code to each page. I would rather set a unique session variable at the start of the session. For this I added into my Global.asax.cs the following:

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                         
            if (Session["LoggedInUser"] == null)
            {
                string networkId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
                using (UnitOfWork unit = new UnitOfWork())
                {                    
                    if (networkId.IndexOf("HLM\\") > -1) { networkId = networkId.Substring(4, networkId.Length - 4); }
                    loggedInUser = unit.PersonRepository.GetByNetworkID(networkId);                                                                              
                    Session["LoggedInUser"] = loggedInUser;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                loggedInUser = (Person)Session["LoggedInUser"];
            }             
        }
```

I now see that it sets the loggedInUser to whatever user last created a session. Meaning, if Mike goes to the site he will see data that represents him as the loggedInUser. However, if Kate goes to the site after him, Mike will now see Kate's data. Basically, the last one in overwrites everyone's settings and Session_Start is overwriting the value for loggedInUser for all active Sessions.

Based on this link: https://books.google.com/books?id=nQkyi4i0te0C&pg=PA202&lpg=PA202&dq=C%23+set+unique+session+variable+in+global.asax&source=bl&ots=GV9nlEUzE5&sig=E4TT3NDbjp1GwEehgU3pLXKdvr0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU9f322tvSAhVF7yYKHYaXCtwQ6AEITzAI#v=onepage&q=C%23%20set%20unique%20session%20variable%20in%20global.asax&f=false
It reads that I should be able to set unique session variables for each new session but my results don't show that.

Am I misunderstanding how this works? I need to set a unique session value at the beginning of each session for each user.

Comment: is "loggedInUser" a static member of your global.asax ?!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The Session_Start is doing what is supposed to at a unique session level. The way I was referencing the session value was all wrong. Instead of accessing the session value I was actually doing:

Person loggedInUser = Global.loggedInUser;

Which makes sense that it was returning the latest user to start a session.